# can this be made easier?

Tags: sql

is there an easier way to do this? i want only households that have charge codes for at least 2 out of 6 years - (cy= current year ly = last year etc. ) ??

```
Exists (SELECT * FROM ac_ViewMultiHouseholdChargeCodeYearCode AS VMH 
WHERE 
aa_Households.HouseholdID = VMH.HouseholdiD and 
VMH.ChargeCode = 'Dinner' and 
(VMH.ChargeCount_CY > 0 and
 (VMH.ChargeCount_LY > 0 or
  VMH.ChargeCount_2Y > 0 or 
  VMH.ChargeCount_3Y > 0 or 
  VMH.ChargeCount_4Y > 0 or 
  VMH.ChargeCount_5Y > 0)) or 
(VMH.ChargeCount_LY > 0 and 
 (VMH.ChargeCount_CY > 0 or
  VMH.ChargeCount_2Y > 0 or
  VMH.ChargeCount_3Y > 0 or 
  VMH.ChargeCount_4Y > 0 or
  VMH.ChargeCount_5Y > 0)) or
(VMH.ChargeCount_2Y > 0 and 
 (VMH.ChargeCount_LY > 0 or
  VMH.ChargeCount_CY > 0 or 
  VMH.ChargeCount_3Y > 0 or
  VMH.ChargeCount_4Y > 0 or
  VMH.ChargeCount_5Y > 0)) or
(VMH.ChargeCount_3Y > 0 and
 (VMH.ChargeCount_LY > 0 or 
  VMH.ChargeCount_2Y > 0 or
  VMH.ChargeCount_CY > 0 or
  VMH.ChargeCount_4Y > 0 or
  VMH.ChargeCount_5Y > 0)) or
(VMH.ChargeCount_4Y > 0 and
 (VMH.ChargeCount_LY > 0 or
  ChargeCount_2Y > 0 or
  VMH.ChargeCount_3Y > 0 or
  VMH.ChargeCount_CY > 0)))
```

Answer (score 5):

You could simplify it to something like:

```
where (
  (case when VMH.ChargeCount_CY > 0 then 1 else 0 end) +
  (case when VMH.ChargeCount_LY > 0 then 1 else 0 end) +
  (case when VMH.ChargeCount_2Y > 0 then 1 else 0 end) +
  (case when VMH.ChargeCount_3Y > 0 then 1 else 0 end) +
  (case when VMH.ChargeCount_4Y > 0 then 1 else 0 end) +
  (case when VMH.ChargeCount_5Y > 0 then 1 else 0 end)
) >= 2
```